# How can I detect if widgets overlap in Stack?

Tags: flutter, stack, widget, overlap

I’m planing to make a simple game in Flutter and in order to do so, I need to detect if some Widgets in Stack overlap(their parts are above each other). Widgets will be moving all the time, so I need to run that check in some kind of a timer.

Any ideas? Nothing crosses my mind.

Comment: check `Rect` class official documentation - it contains the methods to check if two rects overlap

Answer (score 1):

## The timer

The timer problem you can solve with `Timer` class from  [dart-async native package](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/Timer-class.html). The snippet below creates a timer that at each 750 milliseconds will call a function named `_myCallbackFunction`. As an example the callback function can check if there is widget overlap.

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 750), _myCallbackFunction);
```

## The Stack overlap layout

You can use `Positioned` widget from flutter framework to control where your widgets will be placed on the stack.

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(left: 5, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10, child: MyCustomWidget(), ); 
    Positioned(left: 10, top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 0, child: MyCustomWidget(), );
  ]
);
```

## How to check if there is overlap

Well the trick is state management. Assuming that we're using `MyCustomWidget` will be needed store the positional parameters of each `MyCustomWidget` on the stack and eventually check if there is widgets in the same position `top, right, bottom, left`.You can define your logic and I advise you to user [MobX](https://pub.dev/packages/mobx) library to do a easy and powerful state management.